# How can I record audio from the client with python / Flask

Tags: python, flask, speech-recognition, pyaudio

The project :
I'm creating a voice recognition app with Flask and Speech Recognition, that sends triggers to an arduino (Like an alexa).

The Problem:
I used the Microphone() class from Speech Recognition, and until now I thought it was working well.
But yesterday I realised it was actually recording from the microphone of the host computer (I felt like an idiot). I never realised that because I was too close of the host when recording with my phone.

The rules :

The app is a portefolio project, and the rule is to only use Python and Flask to make it. (I tried a javascript code that was really simple and would most likely be the easiest way to do it, but I don't know Javascript that well, and don't want to mislead a possible employer, and it would not feel genuine if he asked about how I wrote those lines of code.)

So here is my question, I don't understand what tool I can use for the microphone to record on the client side.

This is the app (it's in french)

[image]

You click the red button, recording starts, then the word is processed, db is checked, and if the word corresponds to a trigger in the database, it sends it to the serial port and the arduino takes care of the rest. (the form part underneath is to type the word directly for testing purposes)

It's my first question here so I hope i'm clear, don't hesitate to ask for code samples, or clarifications.

Comment: You _can't_ do this without JavaScript, unless your goal is to record audio from the _server_ instead of the client. Your Flask code runs on the server, full stop. It can't access any resources on the client's machine.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your quick answer.

That clarifies everything. 

But are you sure there is absolutely nothing that can be done ? 
I'm going to make a vague theory here, but isn't there any option to create a client side of the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not misleading to an employer to use client-side Javascript in a web app because *everything* short of a completely static website requires some client-side Javascript. In your situation, the Flask app might serve up a view which has Javascript embedded into the templating. As a comment to your question reinforced, your Python code is not going to run in the browser. Its job is done at that point. Use Javascript for the front-end stuff and fulfill your goal by only using Python and Flask on the server-side stuff.

Comment: Okay, I feel a bit dumb for getting that just now after I have been working on flask for the last 2 weeks, but also relieved that it's clear now.
Thank's a lot for these explanations.

Comment: Don't feel dumb! We are so inundated with technology choices that it's easy to forget what does what.

Answer (score 1):

for everyone that's new with Flask or programming like me, this is a vulgarized explanation of what my problem was:

Flask is the code that runs on your server, and your server only.
The client access the templates that result this code, and interract with it through get and post methods.

To allow the client to interract in any other way than POST method (Recording a Vocal Command for example), you need to code on the "front end", Javascript allows you to send instruction to the browser (in my case), that is the Client Application.

If you want to do EVERYTHING with Flask, or Python, you need to code a Client. But that's overkill for my case, I'm just gonna use some Javascript instructions.

thank's a lot to the people who contributed to my learning of basic client-server relationships.